L298N motor driver not working with Arduino UNO R3
I was trying to use the motor driver, but the motors aren't spinning for some reason.
I am sure the motors are working; I tried and tested them. I can't understand if there is a problem with the code, motor driver or the Arduino board.
Arduino board used: Arduino UNO R3
Here is the code:
char data;  //Serial

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (Serial.available()) {
    data = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(data);
  }

  if (data == '1') {
    digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(5,LOW);
    digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(7,LOW);
  }
}


I do not see any problem with your code. However, the code must be compatible with the circuit connections. Please check your whole setup part by part. Check the motor driver with a direct power supply. See if you get the expected output. The motor may not spin due to insufficient voltage and/or current too. So, check your power supply with a multimeter. Since you are sending commands through the serial monitor, check if there has been any baud rate mismatch. You can also check this tutorial for some help: https://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2017/04/dc-motor-direction-control-arduino.html

Thanks!! I found the problem though. Somehow the motors got damaged during soldering.

@KnightRiderDutt you said that you tested the motors

They were working then. No idea what happened
